# Overlap in row values from previous rows

Tags: r

I have a dataframe like this:

```
set.seed(123) 
a <- c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I")
df <- data.frame(
   V1 = sample(a,4, replace=TRUE),
   V2 = sample(a,4, replace=TRUE),
   V3 = sample(a,4, replace=TRUE),
   V4 = sample(a,4, replace=TRUE)
)
```

which looks like

```
  V1 V2 V3 V4
1  C  I  E  G
2  H  A  E  F
3  D  E  I  A
4  H  I  E  I
```

I'd like to count the number of unique values in a row in comparison to the previous rows, so the result would look like:

```
  V1 V2 V3 V4 V5
1  C  I  E  G 4
2  H  A  E  F 3
3  D  E  I  A 2
4  H  I  E  I 1
```

V5 equals 4 for row 1 since it's the 1st row and all are unique

V5 equals 3 for row 2 since H, A, and F were not in row 1

V5 equals 2 for row 3 since 1) D and I were not in row 2.  and 2) D and A were not in row 1.

V5 equals 1 for row 4 since 1) H was not in row 1, 2) I was not in row 2, and 3) H was not in row 4.

if row 4 were H I E A, then V5 for row 4 would have been still been 1 since it only has 1 value not in row 3, even though it would have 2 values not in row 2 and 2 values not in row 1.

Comment: It's probably just me, but I'm having a hard time understanding exactly what you want to do. It seems like you want to compare a given row to all preceding rows and take the minimum of that row-by-row comparison. I.e. if we were looking at row 3, we'd take the minimum of the Row 3 - Row 2 comparison and the Row 3 - Row 1 comparison

Comment: That is correct.   Compare row N to rows 1 to (N-1).  And then find the minimum of those comparisons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a multi-step method in base R.

```
# Create a list of the elements by row, using mike H's method
myList <-  strsplit(Reduce(paste0, df), "")
# previous method, could create new object first t(df) if large df
# myList <-  split(t(df), col(t(df)))

# get pairwise combinations of rows
combos <- t(combn(nrow(df):1, 2))[choose(nrow(df), 2):1,]

# get desired values, sapply runs through pairs of rows, tapply calculates min with row
df$cnts <- c(length(unique(myList[[1]])), # value for first row
             tapply(sapply(1:nrow(combos), # sapply through pairs, taking set diffs
                           function(x) length(setdiff(myList[[combos[x,1]]],
                                                      myList[[combos[x,2]]]))),
                     combos[,1], min)) # split set diff lengths by row, get min length
```

This returns

```
df
  V1 V2 V3 V4 cnts
1  C  I  E  G    4
2  H  A  E  F    3
3  D  E  I  A    2
4  H  I  E  I    1
```

Comment: This works for the example, but how would I change it the values weren't single characters.   For example, what if changed a to   a <- c("Ax123", "B5", "Chess", "Dallas", "Egg", "F", "G2", "H", "I")  ?

Comment: In that instance, you'd have to use my initial method of building the list, which is commented out: `myList <-  split(t(df), col(t(df)))`. As I note, if the size of the data.frame is large, then it may make sense to perform the `t(df)` once: `myRows <- t(df)` and then do `myList <-  split(myRows, col(myRows))`.

Answer (score 1):

For such tasks, storing the rows/sets of data like "df" in a tabulation format can be helpful to solve problems:

```
tab = table(as.matrix(df), row(df)) > 0
#> tab
#   
#        1     2     3     4
#  A FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
#  C  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
#  D FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
#  E  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
#  F FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
#  G  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
#  H FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
#  I  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
```

`crossprod` can be used to retrieve (in a very efficient manner) the number of items that belong to a row but not to any other:

```
ct = crossprod(tab, !tab)
#> ct
#   
#    1 2 3 4
#  1 0 3 2 2
#  2 3 0 2 2
#  3 2 2 0 2
#  4 1 1 1 0
```

Above we can see that, e.g., row 4 contains 1 element that row 1 does not contain, while row 1 contains 2 elements that are not in row 4, etc.

Since here we only care about the previous rows of each row and, specifically, the minimum of each set of one-to-all comparisons, an idea to get the result is:

```
ct[upper.tri(ct, TRUE)] = Inf  ## to ignore 'upper.tri' values in 'max.col'

j_min = max.col(-ct, "first")  ## row-index of the minimum difference per row
c(sum(tab[, 1]), 
  ct[cbind(2:nrow(df), j_min[-1])])
#[1] 4 3 2 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an approach that uses `Reduce` and `mapply`:

```
df$cols_paste <- strsplit(Reduce(paste0, df), split = "")
df$V5 <- lapply(1:length(df$cols_paste), function(x){ 
                                if(x==1) compare = NA
                                else compare = df$cols_paste[seq(1:(x-1))]
                                min(mapply(function(x, y) length(setdiff(x,y)), df$cols_paste[x],  compare))
                                         })

df[,setdiff(names(df), "cols_paste")]
  V1 V2 V3 V4 V5
1  C  I  E  G  4
2  H  A  E  F  3
3  D  E  I  A  2
4  H  I  E  I  1
```